# How do I import NON-CSV-DELIMITED ASCII data into SQLite 3?

Tags: sqlite

How do I import non-CSV ASCII data into SQLite 3?

I have a large amount of newline (0x0A)-terminated ASCII data that I want to import to SQLite 3. I can't use CSV format, because many of the text fields have embedded commas and quotes.  I can reformat the data any which way, but I'd rather not reformat as SQL insert statements (over 400 million rows).

I want the use the ".import" command, which supposedly supports an "ascii" format where a column separator of 0x1F and row separator of 0x1E is used.  Somehow, it doesn't work. I keep getting "Expected 120 columns but found 1".

All the Google results that I'm getting are about CSV import, which is why I'm asking here.

I'm including a simplified example of my problem below. As mentioned, the sample data can contain quotes (single and double), tabs and commas, so I can't use those as delimiters. I can use any other byte value for column and row delimiters.

Example.

Table

```
create table testtable ( item char(20), descr char(30), misc char(40) );
```

Data

| item | descr | misc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | a fruit | no "other" comments, for now |
| grape | another fruit | Yes, I like grapes |

Answer (score 1):

I read through the SQLite3 forums and stumbled on this solution, which isn't really documented fully.

The **-ascii** feature is useless/doesn't work.

```
-- First, I clear my test table
delete from testtable;

-- specify the column delimiter character. I used x1F \036.
-- newline  remains as the record separator (visually easier)
.separator \036

-- import away
.import xxtestdat testtable 

-- verify the load 
.headers on
.mode column

select * from testtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

Where a CSV has (`,`,`\n`) for awk-termed field and record separators, or column and row separators, respectively, Sqlite's `.import --ascii [file] [db]` expects (`\x37`, `\x36`) which are ASCII Unit Separator (us) and Record Separator (rs) of the standard. See `man ascii` or other reference.

#### Demo

Obtain a plain example CSV using `seq 9 | rs -C, 3 | sed 's/,$//' | tee seq.csv`, note no trailing column delimiter.

`<seq.csv tr ',' '\037' | tr '\n' '\036' | tee seq.ascii | less -RF` translates the CSV row and column separators to ASCII unit- and record- separators respectively.

`sqlite3 seq.db '.import --ascii seq.ascii tbl'` imports.

`sqlite3 seq.db '.dump tbl'` shows the imported table.

#### Other hints

In sqlite, if the table does not exist before .import, the first row will become the header. Tables need column names.

In processing other large files, `less -R`, `head -c [char #s]`, and `vim` may be your friend in munging these files and previewing changes.

I found quoting more finicky than I care to understand. bash or command interpret escape sequences in some contexts. `tr` correctly accepts `$'\x1f'` and `'\037'`, but not `"\x1f"`. Note tr accepts multichar arguments, so quoting is essential, `tr , \x1f` vs `tr , '\x1f'` makes a difference. gnu-sed adds a later stage of interpretation.

#### Other selected references

```sh
$ printf "\036\037 \x1e\x1f" | xxd
00000000: 1e1f 201e 1f                             .. ..
```

from `man ascii`,

- in octal:

  `034 fs   035 gs   036 rs   037 us`
- and hexadecimal:

  `1c fs    1d gs    1e rs    1f us`.

Sqlite also allows specifying other column, and optionally row, separators.
`.separator COL ?ROW?     Change the column and row separators`